# Как присвоить значение аргумента логгеру slf4j

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, slf4j

Приложение запускается следующим образом: `java -jar app.jar logfile.txt`. Аргумент получать умею, но как мне установить его логгеру в виде пути до файла? В файле конфигурации это выглядело бы следующим образом: `logging.file.path`, но изначально путь неизвестен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось реализовать таким образом:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String logfile = "";
    try { 
        logfile = args[1]; 
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}

    new SpringApplicationBuilder(VkApplication.class)
            .properties("logging.file.name=" + logfile).run(args);

    if(logfile.isEmpty()) {
        log.warn("Log file hasn't been present. Logging will out just in a console.");
    }
}
```

Свойства назначил через `SpringApplicationBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

В `Spring` все значения переопределяются через двойное тире **--**.
Как-то пытаться делать это через код кажется мне очень плохой идеей. Такие вещи как путь до файла с логами в основном делают через **переменные окружения** или **в команде запуска**.

То есть команда запуска будет такая `java -jar app.jar --logging.file.path=logfile.txt`

А если через переменные окружения, то нужно отредактировать application.* ::

```
logging:
  file:
    path: ${LOGGIN_FILE_PATH:<DEFAULT_VALUE>}
```

И тогда `Spring` сам подхватит значение `LOGGING_FILE_PATH` из `Environment` (переменных окружения). Если же он не найдет значение, то будет использовать значение по умолчанию `<DEFAULT_VALUE>` (только писать без ковычек), которое вы задали после двоеточия

Через код это можно сделать так ::

```
public interface EnvironmentProperties {

    String LOGGING_FILE_PATH = "LOGGING_FILE_PATH";

}
```

И в методе `main(String[] args)` ::

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty(EnvironmentProperties.LOGGING_FILE_PATH, args[0]);
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Я с вами полностью согласен. Для прода это ни куда не годится, но того требует задание в виде вступительного испытания на стажировку от ВК. Как обычно, понапридумывают всякого))  Если интересно, вот ссылка: https://like-brace-188.notion.site/ae0c46a02f994309b4848c9a912752e1

Comment: Тогда можно через `System.setProperty("LOGGING_FILE_PATH", args[0])` в методе `main`, где запуск приложения идёт. Обновлю ответ